# Does the iOS App development certificate CSR email field need to be an apple ID?

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning

Does the iOS App development certificate CSR email field need to be an apple ID or can it be any e-mail address?

Comment: Sorry about my previous comment. User email and name can be anything you want. AC email should be empty.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the email associated with your Developer Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It does not require Apple Id in email field of CSR. It can be any email address.